# apache vhosts on mac not being recognized

Tags: macos, apache

I'm trying to enable vhosts, however for some reason it's not being recognized.

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
127.0.0.1       trekfed.cutlerplace.net
```

/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so

# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/*.conf
```

/private/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/trekfed.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    LogLevel info

    ServerName trekfed.cutlerplace.net
    ServerAdmin cheng@trekfederation.com

    # Static files
    DocumentRoot "/Users/arcee123/Documents/trekfed"
    Alias /static/ /Users/arcee123/Documents/trekfed/static/

    <Directory "/Users/arcee123/Documents/trekfed/static">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # WGSI configuration
    WSGIDaemonProcess trekfed.cutlerplace.net processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/Users/arcee123/Documents/trekfed/:/Users/arcee123/Documents/VirtualEnvs/venv-trek/lib/python3.5/site-packages

    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/arcee123/Documents/trekfed/trekfed/wsgi.py

    <Directory "/Users/arcee123/Documents/trekfed">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I perform a `apachectl -S`, This is the response:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd24"
Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/local/var/www/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="daemon" id=1
Group: name="daemon" id=1
```

when I run `apachectl configtest` I'm expecting warnings for the two vhosts, and any warnings (if needed) for the other one.  but the only response I get is `Syntax OK`

What am I missing?  I can't tell what I'm missing to get the vhosts going.  The only response I get from putting the vhost address into the browser is the default apache response.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to change `dummy-host.example.com` to `trekfed.cutlerplace.net`...

Comment: That's already in place in the trekfed.conf file

Comment: Is `/private/etc/apache2/extra` a file or directory ... and what is in `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`?

Comment: sorry.  it is the file.  I updated the query.

Comment: One last question, have you tried specifically including `trekfed.conf` instead of just `*.conf` ?

Comment: yes.  I even put the direct path and filename into httpd.conf, no dice.